# Regex.test is giving me an error

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have the following javascript...

```
$.post(url, data, function (json) {
        var patt = new RegExp('/^\[{"dID":/');
        if (patt.test(json)) {

            //output json results formatted
} else {

        //error so output json string
            $('#diaryTable').replaceWith(json);    

        }
    }, 'json');
```

Basically my json should either be a valid json which begins with

**[{"dID":**

or it will be

**[{** *the ex.Message from try catch exception...* **}]**

Unfotunately I get the error **JavaScript runtime error: Expected ']' in regular expression**

I have check my RegEx /^[{"dID":/ at RegEx101.com with some test data and my test worked as expected. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: `var patt = /^\[\{"dID":/;`

Comment: You need to escape the `[` bracket, as otherwise it acts as a Regex operator. If you want to test regex, I find `regexr` to be the best site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to all who tried to help... I think my explanation of the problem was not too clear...

I've fixed my issue by checking if I have a valid object... a valid object will have a dID value so I have used...

```
 if (typeof json[0].dID != 'undefined') {
            // valid object
            var out = "";
            var i;
            var a = "N"

            for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                out += '<div class="dOuter' + a + '">';
                out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dDate + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dRef + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dTeam + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dCreatedBy + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dType ' + json[i].dType + '">' + json[i].dType + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dServer">' + json[i].dServer + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dComment">' + htmlEncode(json[i].dComment) + '</div></div>';

                if (a == "N") {
                    a = "A";
                } else {
                    a = "N";
                }
            }

            $('#diaryTable').replaceWith(out);
        }

        else { 
            //error so output json string
            $('#diaryTable').replaceWith(json);    
        }
```